# Prevent adding total price from another parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

This script is working if I have listed only one product. The total is adding from another div parent. What is the best practice to keep the script for individual div only?

I have 50 products in a single page, I just shown two in this snippet. Here's the snippet of the script:

https://jsfiddle.net/jboiler/vopa8qt7/30/

```
<div>
  <div class="single-product-items">
    <div>
      <h5>
        <a>Product 1
      </a>
      </h5>
      <span class="current-price">350</span>
    </div>
    <div class="varSelectorBtns">
      <div class="shirtColor"><button value="0" class="White"></button><button value="80" class="Black"></button><button value="80" class="Gray"></button><button class="DarkGray" value="10"></button><button value="80" class="NavyBlue"></button><button value="80" class="Red"></button><button value="80" class="Yellow"></button><button value="80" class="Green"></button><button value="80" class="Blue"></button><button class="Pink" value="30"></button></div>
      <div class="shirtSize "><button value="0">XS</button><button value="0">S</button><button value="0">M</button><button value="0">L</button><button value="0">XL</button><button value="20">XXL</button><button value="30">3XL</button><button value="50">5XL</button></div>
      <div class="shirtQlty "><button value="0">Ordinary</button><button value="68">Premium</button></div>
      <div>
        <button>Add To Cart</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Same code for the Product 2, Product 3 and so on....

Below is the script

```
 let subtotalprice = 0;
    let sizePrice = 0;
    let qualityPrice = 0;
    let colorPrice = 0;

    let baseprice = 350;

// SIZE BUTTONS
    
    $(".shirtSize button").click(function() {
      sizeVal = $(this).text();
      sizePrice = $(this).val();
    
      subtotalprice = parseInt(baseprice) + parseInt(sizePrice) + parseInt(qualityPrice) + parseInt(colorPrice);
     
      $(this).closest('.single-product-items').find('.current-price').text( subtotalprice); //change displayed current price

    });
    
    
   
// COLOR BUTTONS

$(".shirtColor button").click(function() {
    colorVal = $(this).text();
    colorPrice = $(this).val();
  
    subtotalprice = parseInt(baseprice) + parseInt(sizePrice) + parseInt(qualityPrice) + parseInt(colorPrice);
   
    $(this).closest('.single-product-items').find('.current-price').text(subtotalprice); //change displayed current price

  });

// QUALITY BUTTONS
           
$(".shirtQlty button").click(function() {
    qualityVal = $(this).text();
    qualityPrice = $(this).val();
  
    subtotalprice = parseInt(baseprice) + parseInt(sizePrice) + parseInt(qualityPrice) + parseInt(colorPrice);
   
    $(this).closest('.single-product-items').find('.current-price').text(subtotalprice); //change displayed current price

  });
```

Comment: Application state management with jQuery is hard. I'd suggest looking into modern frameworks such as React or Vue. If you can't use them - you could use data attributes to store current values, like $(smth).data(...)

Comment: @MaximMazurok, converting my whole site to React would be a hard and long work for me.. I will just try your suggestion to store from data attributes. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To keep JavaScript code specific to an individual div element, you can use the `getElementById` or `querySelector` method to target the div by its id or class.

JavaScript:

```
const product1 = document.getElementById('#product1');
const product2 = document.getElementById('#product2');
// or
// const product1 = document.querySelector('#product1');
// const product2 = document.querySelector('#product2');

// add an event listener to the div
product1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // code specific to this div goes here
});

product2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // code specific to this div goes here
});
```

Or

Use a JavaScript module if you have a large amount of JavaScript code specific to the div, you can encapsulate it in a JavaScript module. This will keep the code separate from other parts of your code and make it easier to maintain.

Comment: I thought of that way, but I have 50 products in a single page. I guess using ID's is inefficient.